# How do I bind rows efficiently in for loop and lapply for a big dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, row, bind, lapply

I have a for loop and a lapply function

```
for (x in y) {
  x1 = x + 1
  x2 = x - z + 1 
  
  line = lapply(datafr), function(cols) {
    df_i = datafr %>% filter 
    df_spread = tidyr::spread(df_i, var1, cols)
    cn = c(cols, paste0(cols, "_minus_", abs(cn[-1])))
    colnames(df_spread) = cn
    df_spread
  })
  
  df_i = data.frame(var1 = datafr$value1, list.cbind(line))
  df_i
}
```

so df_1 is one single row and I want to bind all the df_i in the loop the fastest way possible, since the dataframe is pretty big. I considered usind rbind or bind_rows but would that be efficient?

Comment: `df_i = datafr %>% filter`, whatever it does, is inefficient there since you do it for every iteration in the lapply and  in the for loop and from what we see here it seems it would yield the same result every time. calling `dplyr::bind_rows()` on a list of data frames is efficient. An alternative is `data.table::rind.list()`

Comment: Also this code doesn't work..